# Client-side JavaScript Socket.io connection based on dynamic url possible?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying out some dynamic options for storing environment variables throughout a distributed app.  I'm struggling with combining a simple Socket.io with chat page with connection based on a URL from a config.json file.  I thought it would be clever on page load to fetch the json file and feed the URL to the socket object.  However, I keep running into a chicken and egg issue with the async processing. With what I have right now it starts the connection with the startSocket() function but I would like to have the socket variable available for other functions such as the event listener for the message form.  Is there a better way to handle the Socket object get me out of this mess?  Obviously new to web dev.

```
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')
const name = document.getElementById('chatUserField').getAttribute('data-chatUsername');

fetch('./assets/config.json')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => {
        startSocket(JSON.stringify(data.SocketIO_URL).replace(/['"]+/g, ''))
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))


function startSocket(url) {
    const socket = io(url)

    appendMessage('you joined')
    socket.emit('new-user', name)

    socket.on('chat-message', data => {
        appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
    })

    socket.on('user-connected', name => {
        appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
    })

    socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
        appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
    })
}

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const message = messageInput.value
    appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
    socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
    messageInput.value = ''
})

function appendMessage(message) {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
    messageElement.innerText = message
    messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things going on here. The reason why you're getting the error, I presume, is not because of the async question you describe—rather it's because in the event listener, you have the following line:

```
socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
```

However, `socket` isn't defined here within that function. You defined it in the `startSocket` function but it's [locally scoped](https://codeburst.io/javascript-a-basic-guide-to-scope-9682d57be6fc), meaning that outside of the code in `startSocket`, you can't access it.

Generally you want to add event listeners and all the stuff that depends on the loaded config in the promise `.then` handler, since JavaScript will then only run that when your config file is loaded (which is what you want!).

So I would return the socket object from `startSocket`:

```
function startSocket(url) {
    const socket = io(url)

    appendMessage('you joined')
    socket.emit('new-user', name)

    socket.on('chat-message', data => {
        appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
    })

    socket.on('user-connected', name => {
        appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
    })

    socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
        appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
    })
    return socket;
}
```

Then I would assign it to a variable in the `.then` handler.

```
fetch('./assets/config.json')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => {
        // do all processing related to setting stuff up now here
        const mySocket = startSocket(JSON.stringify(data.SocketIO_URL).replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
        // now that we have the socket object, let's set up the event listeners
        messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const message = messageInput.value
            appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
            mySocket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
            messageInput.value = ''
        })
    })
```

Comment: Ah gotcha, I didn't think to return the socket.  Knew I had a scope issue but was missing the pass-of-the-torch element here.  Thanks, this is a great help!